# How to delete from an array javascript?

Tags: javascript

My code below opens a random website from the array but to stop going on the same website is there a way to delete it once it has been visited. Heres my attempt.

```
<button onclick="randomLink()";>Click here to go somewhere else!</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var randomLink = function () {

    var links = new Array(); 
        links[1] = "http://google.com";
        links[2]="http://bing.com";

    var max = (links.length)


    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);


    var link = links[randomNumber];

    links.splice(randomNumber,1);


    $('iframe').attr('src', link);
}
</script>

<iframe src="" name="iframe_a" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Define `links` outside of the function. You're deleting an item using `splice` but then putting it back when you run the function again.

Comment: In addition to @MikeC, as a suggestion, don't define arrays with keys. You are missing the `links[0]` key and you can have problems. It's better if you don't define the key, it will be asigned automatically by javascript

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random()*max)` Can give 2 and will work incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `links` outside of the function:

```
var links = [
  "http://google.com",
  "http://bing.com"
];

var randomLink = function() {
  var max = links.length;
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  var link = links[randomNumber];
  links.splice(randomNumber, 1);
  $('iframe').attr('src', link);
};
```

Comment: I think it´s `Math.random() * (max-1)`. You could also just do `var link = links.splice(Math.random() * (links.length-1), 1)` and remove 4 lines

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the function, all url's are added to the array. Try to define the array outside the function.
To delete something call splice!

best,
Sebi

Answer (score 0):

This is true code, you have ; after "".

```html
<button onclick="randomLink()">Click here to go somewhere else!</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var randomLink = function () {

    var links = new Array(); 
        links[1] = "http://google.com";
        links[2]="http://bing.com";

    var max = (links.length)


    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);


    var link = links[randomNumber];

    links.splice(randomNumber,1);


    $('iframe').attr('src', link);
}
</script>

<iframe src="" name="iframe_a" ></iframe>
```

Comment: That's a minor typo, not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do it using `splice` for example we have arr :

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

To remove `arr[2]` which hold the value of `3` we can do :

```
arr.splice(2,1);
```

`arr` will become `[1,2,4,5,6]`

3 is the previous index of the deleted value and 1 is how many values to delete after that index .

You can read more about `splice` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) .